# Counting number of books sold in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, countif

I need help with setting up the counting function in spreadsheet.

So I have 1 sheet to record all book sales transaction (let's call it sheet A), 1 sheet for all books purchases (sheet B), and one to keep track of books in stock (sheet C).

In sheet C, I use countif function to have 1 column with the number of books sold, 1 column with the number of books purchased. When I take the second column and subtract the first column, I should have the number of books in stock.

However, since the countif function only count the frequency the title of the books appear in either sheet A or B, and not how many of them were actually purchased/sold, I can't get an accurate number on how many books I still have left. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Here is the sheet in question. Feel free to edit it if you guys want: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oM-GG5WOh1ipujx3lf2w6GAi9nJDA5YZIb5BBNQZZvU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest..

1) getting the unique book titles, with the formula

```
=query(unique({'Book sold'!C6:C; 'Book purchased'!C6:C}), "where Col1 <>''",0)
```

2) use VLOOKUP to get the sold and purchased values

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B6:B), iferror(vlookup(B6:B, 'Book sold'!C6:D, 2, 0), 0),))
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B6:B), iferror(vlookup(B6:B, 'Book purchased'!C6:D, 2, 0), 0),))
```

3) calculate the difference between both columns, using

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(D6:D)*len(C6:C), D6:D-C6:C,))
```

On the sheet you shared, see sheet 'In stock JP' for an example.
Hope that helps ?

Note that if a book would occur on more than one row in the same sheet, the above won't work and a different approach is needed. For an example of such a 'different' approach see sheet 'Copy of In stock JP', where I used a query as 'VLOOKUP'-range. E.g:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B6:B), iferror(vlookup(B6:B, query('Book sold'!C6:D, "Select C, sum(D) group by C "), 2, 0), 0),))
```